# Getting wrong output with linq join query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have this data:**Users**

```
UserId   Name
 42      Abc  
 43      Pqr
 44      lmn
 45      xyz
```

**Mappings**:

```
MappingId  User1  User2  
1           42    43
2           42    44 
3           43    44
```

I want to get all user that is `user2` which is not in `user 1` and so the output will be below considering above input:

**Expected Output**:

```
UserId   Name
 44       lmn
```

This is my query:

```
var data = (from user in context.Users
                            join mappng in context.Mappings on user.UserId equals mappng.User2
                            where mappng.User1 != mappng.User2
                            select new 
                            {
                                Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                                UserId = user.UserId,
                            }).ToList();
```

But getting wrong output:

```
UserId   Name
43       Pqr
44       lmn
44       lmn
```

Note: There is no foreign key relationship and so no navigation property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution to your problem in a console application. I used where !(..) to find those not in mappings User1. I'm not sure of other alternatives to this approach. But hope it helps.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User() { UserId = 42, Name = "Abc" },
            new User() { UserId = 43, Name = "Pqr" },
            new User() { UserId = 44, Name = "lmn" },
            new User() { UserId = 45, Name = "xyz" },
        };

        List<UserMapping> userMappings = new List<UserMapping>()
        {
            new UserMapping() { MappingId = 1, User1 = 42, User2 = 43},
            new UserMapping() { MappingId = 2, User1 = 42, User2 = 44},
            new UserMapping() { MappingId = 3, User1 = 43, User2 = 44},
        };

        var data = (from u in users
                        join m in userMappings on u.UserId equals m.User2
                        where !(from mm in userMappings
                               select mm.User1).Contains(u.UserId)
                        select u).Distinct();

        foreach(var entry in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.UserId + " " + entry.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class UserMapping
{
    public int MappingId { get; set; }
    public int User1 { get; set; }
    public int User2 { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
44 lmn
```

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ posted compares `User1` and `User2` values of the same row by using `mappng.User1 != mappng.User2`, which isn't the wanted query. Try using `!Any()` as follow :

```
var data = (from user in context.Users
            join mappng in context.Mappings on user.UserId equals mappng.User2
            where !context.Mappings.Any(m => m.User1 == user.UserId)
            select new 
            {
                Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                UserId = user.UserId,
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Getting userid 45 2 times.

Comment: @Learning added `.Distinct()` to fix that

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.It is working.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var data = (from map1 in context.Mappings 
            join map2 in context.Mappings 
            on map1.User2 equals map2.User1 into subMap
            from sub in subMap.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where sub == null
            join user in context.Users on map1.User2 equals user.UserId
            select new {
                 Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                 user.UserId,
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.It is working.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this code snipped.

```
var result = context.Mappings.Where(mapping1 => !context.Mappings.Select(mapping2 => mapping2.User1).Contains(mapping1.User2))
            .Select(e=> e.User2).Distinct()
            .Join(context.Users, arg => arg, user=> user.UserId,(arg,user) => user)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.It is working.Thank you so much

Comment: @Learning, I think, that this answer is wrong, try this [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lc5CGA)

Comment: @Slava Utesinov fix it

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this.

```
var data = (select user from context.Users where (from m2 in context.Mappings select m2.User2).Except(from m1 in context.Mappings select m1.User1).Contains(user.UserId) select new {Name=user.Name, UserId=user.UserId}).ToList();
```

I don't see the user.FirstName, user.LastName in example table. 
So you can revise new object by yourself if this solution is work.

Comment: Please format your code by selecting your code and press ctrl + k.Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for advising me the tip.